# importing from subdirectories in Python

Tags: python, import

I am new to Python and I am confused in importing files from subdirectories. My filesystem structure is as follows:

```
/doc/a/main.py

      /second.py

/doc/b/prog.py
```

Now I want to import main and second in prog.py. Can anyone suggest me a method to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../a")
import main, second
```

and then call `prog.py` while in directory `b`.

Answer (score 4):

First you should learn what a proper Python package makes: it needs to contain a file named `__init__.py`

The search path of Python can be configured either by modifying sys.path or setting the $PYTHONPATH environment variable.

See also

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

or google for "python import pythonpath"