# Why am i unable to run my project from the command line?

Tags: python, initialization, project, modulenotfounderror

I have created a simple app, doesn't matter what is the purpose but i was trying to run it from the command line but it does not work. I am able to run it and everything from the IDE (PyCharm) but not CLI.

I have **init** files in every folder and the folder structure looks like this:

```
Project
├───.idea
│   └───inspectionProfiles
├───files
└───src
    ├───project
    │   ├───Variations
    │   │   └───__init__.py
    │   │   └───A.py
    │   │   └───B.py
    │   └───__init__.py
    │   └───C.py
    │   └───D.py
    └────tests
        └───__init__.py
        └───main.py
```

When i positioned myself in tests and ran:
`python main.py` the script returned:

```
 File "G:\Projects\ExampleProject\src\tests\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from project import run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

Comment: The issue might be that `main.py` can't find `project` because they aren't in the same folder. You may need to [add your module to `sys.path`](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-import-module-search-path/).

Comment: @AliasCartellano when i print out the sys.path with pprint it has 'G:\\Projects\\ExampleProject' in it. Am i doing something wrong? Also if i wanted for anyone to use my code, so im wondering how would I make it possible for them? I want to learn how to make my whole project executable

Comment: You can try [importing the files you need directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180215/importing-from-subdirectories-in-python). Look at [Convert Python to exe](https://copyassignment.com/convert-python-to-exe/).